# Пунктуация в цитате из Паустовского

Tags: пунктуация

*Я слышал разговоры – пьяные и трезвые, робкие и отчаянные, полные покорности и злобы, – всякие разговоры.*
[**К. Г. Паустовский**](https://project1917.ru/posts/7642/##post)

Почему после слова "разговоры" ставится тире?

Comment: ...пьяные и трезвые... вероятно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Почему после слова "разговоры" ставится тире?

Потому что автору захотелось обозначить в этом месте паузу. Другой автор мог бы тире и не поставить.

Comment: Jasmin, чтобы отсрочить переход в рекомендованный нам с Вами чат,  решил продолжить обсуждение здесь. С тем, что первое тире необязательно, Вы уже согласились. Теперь по поводу Вашего "но тогда, наверное, и запятую ставить не надо". Давайте попробуем выкинуть из предложения часть определений: _Я слышал разговоры,  полные покорности и злобы (?) всякие разговоры._ Какой знак или знаки Вы бы поставили на месте скобок?

Answer (score 2):

Я слышал разговоры – пьяные и резвые, робкие и отчаянные, полные покорности и злобы, – всякие разговоры (Паустовский).

Структура у предложения *нестандартная*: обособленный с помощью тире ряд однородных определений + повтор определяемого слова с обобщающим определением. *Поэтому все знаки требуют объяснения, а не только тире.*

Можно рассмотреть два варианта построения предложения.

1) Берем первую часть предложения:  Я слышал разговоры – пьяные и резвые, робкие и отчаянные, полные покорности и злобы. Здесь тире ставится по обычным правилам. А теперь добавим обобщающее словосочетание, перед ним ставим единый знак "запятая-тире".

2) Я слышал разговоры, всякие разговоры. А теперь добавляем ряд определений, обособляя его с помощью тире.

Comment: _1) Берем первую часть предложения: Я слышал разговоры – пьяные и резвые, робкие и отчаянные, полные покорности и злобы. **Здесь тире ставится по обычным правилам**._ === Сможете ли назвать правила, заставляющие поставить **здесь** тире? Разве не может приведённая Вами часть предложения быть написанной без тире?

Comment: У Розенталя: Обособленное определение, стоящее в конце предложения, особенно при перечислении, может отделяться не запятой, а тире: Меня всегда интересовал этот дом в старинном переулке — мрачно-таинственный, благородный всем своим видом, ни на один другой не похожий.http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=109#pp109

Comment: Первое тире можно и не ставить, но тогда, наверное,  и запятую ставить не надо, хватит одного второго тире перед обобщением.

Comment: _У Розенталя: Обособленное определение, стоящее в конце предложения, особенно при перечислении, может отделяться не запятой, а тире..._ === Смешно! Т. е. Вы считаете, что в приведённой Вами части предложения перед определениями обязательно должна стоять либо запятая, либо тире? А не ближе ли к разбираемому предложению след. строки из Розенталя: _Не обособляются распространенные определения...2) стоящие после существительного, если последнее само по себе в данном предложении не выражает нужного смысла и нуждается в определении_?

Comment: _Первое тире **можно** и не ставить, но тогда, **наверное**, и запятую ставить не надо..._ === Ключевое слово у Вас здесь -- **наверное**... Да, и **можно**. Т. е. можно и ставить. Как я понял, своё **"Здесь тире ставится по обычным правилам"** Вы своим вторым комментарием сами же и опровергли.

Comment: Обычное правило - это обособление однородного ряда (определений или приложений) в конце предложения. Одиночное определение в постпозиции может обособляться или нет - это тоже обычное правило.  А вообще обычные правила удобно применять для стандартного синтаксиса, а здесь он нестандартный. В таких случаях надо определить структуру предложения, а уже потом ставить знаки препинания.  Именно это я и пыталась сделать и даже с Вами хотела посоветоваться - отсюда и ключевое слово "наверное". Сначала я хотела написать: "А Вы как думаете?"